# date_format without day or without month in PHP

Tags: php, date

I have a date in this way: `2014-10-20` in a variable, using:

```
date_format($myDateTime, "M jS, Y");
```

I get this output: `Oct 20th, 2014`, which is ok up until now. The problem comes up when my variable have something like this: `2014-10-00` which using:

```
$date_format($myDateTime, "M Y");
```

I get this: `Sep 2014` when It is suppose to be `Oct 2014` (even using `$myDateTime->modify('+1 month')` does not work), or when I have this one `2014-00-00` using this:

```
date_format($myDateTime, "Y");
```

I get: `2013`

How can I get the proper formatted date? Thanks.

Comment: There is no day `0` in the month. October 0 is the day before October 1, which is September 30.

Comment: And 2014-00-00 is really 2013-12-31.

Comment: Where are these nonexistent dates coming from?

Comment: Poster, the problem is you put invalid dates such as 2014-10-00 the system actually chooses the greatest matching date which is 2014-09-30 (Because 20141001 is greater than 20141000 and it automatically says that can't be the answer).  In your 2014-00-00 example, it picks 2013-12-31.  That's just how php works.  If you are trying to make it give a greater date to an invalid...well you are going to have it make a lot of code to solve this.

Comment: Just look for "00" in your var and replace it with "01". It's dirty solution but at least it will not affect other components of date when one is zeroed.

Comment: I need it in this way, cuz it is for birth dates, and sometimes the day and month is completely unknown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`2014-10-00` and `2014-00-00` is not valid dates. I think you see it. But you know your own format and can parse it manually (explode by `-` or match regex and parse each element) or change format to correct (use -01 instead -00).

Case 1 (explode):

```
$date = '2014-00-00'; // We need to get year
$dateParts = explode('-', $date);
$year = (int)$dateParts[0];
```

Case 2 (regex):

```
$date = '2014-10-00';
if (preg_match('/^([0-9]{4})\-([0-9]{2})\/', $date, $matches)) {
    $year = (int)$matches[1];
    $month = (int)$matches[2];
} else {
    throw new \Exception('Invalid date format');
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: I think this is the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could devise something that would be accepted by `DateTime`. You could anticipate `Y-m-00`, `Y-00-00`, or the valid one `Y-m-d` using `date_parse` if you're just gunning for year, month, and day:

```
// $date_string = '2014-10-20';
// $date_string = '2014-10-00';
$date_string = '2014-00-00';
$d = date_parse($date_string);
$myDateTime = new DateTime();
$myDateTime->setDate($d['year'], $d['month'] ? $d['month'] : 1, $d['day'] ? $d['day'] : 1);
print_r($myDateTime);
```

Sidenote: If in case, your input is `Y-00-00`, then this will set your current date month and day with the corresponding input year.

Answer (score -2):

Use `date()` instead of others.

Look http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_date.asp

Example:

```
<?php
echo date("Y-m-d");
?>
```

**Year only:**

```
<?php
echo date("Y");
?>
```

**Short Month and Year (e.g. Jan 2016)**

```
<?php
echo date("M").' '.date("Y");
?>
```

Comment: I'm really wondering, what's your exact way to push parameter like string "2014-00-00" into date() function!?

Comment: @Wh1T3h4Ck5 - can you explain?

Comment: Can you please read the question.... OP gets illegal date strings, output is not a problem in the first place. Or to be more specific... your input is "2014-00-00" which is invalid date, tell me how to get 2014 as a year using date() function and that input string, or how to get "Oct 2014" for input "2014-10-00" which is also part of question?

Comment: No, use DateTime objects and functions instead of archaic calls prone to gross misuse.